# How does basic models.py and controllers.py look in Flask?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How does basic models.py and controllers.py look, What is the basic structure of it? or a template?

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/carpedm20/personal-blog-powered-by-flask/blob/master/app/models.py

Answer (score 1):

`models.py`

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import db
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))

def __init__(self, name, email, password):
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.password = generate_password_hash(password)

def check_password(self, password):
    return check_password_hash(self.password, password)

def to_dict(self):
    return {
        'id' : self.id,
        'name': self.name,
        'email': self.email,
    }

def __repr__(self):
    return "User<%d> %s" % (self.id, self.name)
```

or

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import db

class Todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'todos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    text = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    color = db.Column(db.String(24))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    done = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def __init__(self, title, text, color, user_id):
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
        self.color = color
        self.user_id = user_id

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'title': self.title,
            'text': self.text,
            'color': self.color,
            'done': self.done,
        }

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Todo<%d> %s" % (self.id, self.title)
```

`controllers.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, session, jsonify
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from app import db
from .models import User

mod_user = Blueprint('user', __name__, url_prefix='/api')


@mod_user.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def check_login():
    if 'user_id' in session:
        user = User.query.filter(User.id == session['user_id']).first()
        return jsonify(success=True, user=user.to_dict())

    return jsonify(success=False), 401


@mod_user.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    try:
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
    except KeyError as e:
        return jsonify(success=False, message="%s not sent in the request" % e.args), 400

    user = User.query.filter(User.email == email).first()
    if user is None or not user.check_password(password):
        return jsonify(success=False, message="Invalid Credentials"), 400

    session['user_id'] = user.id

    return jsonify(success=True, user=user.to_dict())


@mod_user.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    session.pop('user_id')
    return jsonify(success=True)


@mod_user.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
    try:
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
    except KeyError as e:
        return jsonify(success=False, message="%s not sent in the request" % e.args), 400

    if '@' not in email:
        return jsonify(success=False, message="Please enter a valid email"), 400

    u = User(name, email, password)
    db.session.add(u)
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        return jsonify(success=False, message="This email already exists"), 400

    return jsonify(success=True)
```

or

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, session, jsonify
from app import db, requires_auth
from .models import Todo

mod_todo = Blueprint('todo', __name__, url_prefix='/api')

@mod_todo.route('/todo', methods=['POST'])
@requires_auth
def create_todo():
    title = request.form['title']
    text = request.form['text']
    color = request.form['color']
    user_id = session['user_id']
    todo = Todo(title, text, color, user_id)
    db.session.add(todo)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(success=True, todo=todo.to_dict())

@mod_todo.route('/todo', methods=['GET'])
@requires_auth
def get_all_todos():
    user_id = session['user_id']
    todos = Todo.query.filter(Todo.user_id == user_id).all()
    return jsonify(success=True, todos=[todo.to_dict() for todo in todos])

@mod_todo.route('/todo/<id>', methods=['GET'])
@requires_auth
def get_todo(id):
    user_id = session['user_id']
    todo = Todo.query.filter(Todo.id == id, Todo.user_id == user_id).first()
    if todo is None:
        return jsonify(success=False), 404
    else:
        return jsonify(success=True, todo=todo.to_dict())

@mod_todo.route('/todo/<id>', methods=['POST'])
@requires_auth
def edit_todo(id):
    user_id = session['user_id']
    todo = Todo.query.filter(Todo.id == id, Todo.user_id == user_id).first()
    if todo is None:
        return jsonify(success=False), 404
    else:
        todo.title = request.form['title']
        todo.text = request.form['text']
        todo.color = request.form['color']
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(success=True)

@mod_todo.route('/todo/<id>/done', methods=['POST'])
@requires_auth
def mark_done(id):
    user_id = session['user_id']
    todo = Todo.query.filter(Todo.id == id, Todo.user_id == user_id).first()
    if todo is None:
        return jsonify(success=False), 404
    else:
        todo.done = True
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(success=True)


@mod_todo.route('/todo/<id>/delete', methods=['POST'])
@requires_auth
def delete_todo(id):
    user_id = session['user_id']
    todo = Todo.query.filter(Todo.id == id, Todo.user_id == user_id).first()
    if todo is None:
        return jsonify(success=False), 404
    else:
        db.session.delete(todo)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(success=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for the answer. Adding description to your answer will make it clear to the reader. Your description could contain the directory structure, the need for Blueprint, and so on.